# What to return on clicking submit button using formcontroller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, return-value, formcollection

I'm working on MVC3, i have to add user to DB from front end.I'm using formcollection.i'm using following buttons inside formtag,

```
     <td> <input type="submit" class="btn" name="adduser" id="btnAdd" value="Add/Edit User" /></td> 
    <td> <input type="submit" class="btn" name="cancel" id="btnCancel" value="Cancel" /></td>
```

following is my controller method,

```
       public ActionResult TravelReadyAdminAccess(FormCollection Collection, string adduser, string cancel)
    {
        TravelReadyAdminBLL objTravelReadyAdminBLL = new TravelReadyAdminBLL();
        try
        {
            int intLoggedinUserId = 0;
            int intMappedUserId = 0;
            intLoggedinUserId = Convert.ToInt32(Collection["loggedinuser"]);
            intMappedUserId = Convert.ToInt32(Collection["mappeduser"]);
            var button = adduser ?? cancel;
            if (button == "Add/Edit User")
            {
                objTravelReadyAdminBLL.TravelReadyAddUser(intLoggedinUserId, intMappedUserId);
                ViewData["EditUser"] = "User Added Sucessfully";
            }
            else if (button == "Cancel")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("TravelReadyAdminAccess");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("TravelReadyAdminAccess");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ILogManager LogManager = new LogManager();
            var frame = new StackFrame(0);
            LogManager.CallLogging(frame, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            return RedirectToAction("Error", "Common");
        }
    }
```

i want to get the success message when user added..what i need to return in the controller method?

Comment: You can try to use JavascriptResult
return JavaScriptResult("alert('user added');");

Answer (score 0):

You can use **viewbag** in your action method and pass bool value to it. Say for e.g. **true for success** and **false in case of failure** and access this viewbag in your view.